# How to add Navigation Architecture while using tabs

Tags: android, view, architecture, navigation, androidx

I have an application that implements a Bottom Navigation Layout. It contains 4 tabs. The first tab is the NavHost. This tab has an inner View Pager that contains 2 tabs (fragments).
However how can I connect the inner View Pager on the Navigation Graph?

Below is the image of the application itself:

[image: tion]ollowing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a ViewPager, you'd continue to use a ViewPager, passing it `getChildFragmentManager()` as per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122087752) - you wouldn't put the Fragments in your ViewPager in your navigation graph.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however how can I implement the click listener (should open a fragment) when an item on the recycler view is clicked?

Comment: You can still call `findNavController()` from child Fragments